# django-elasticsearch error : [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

I'm trying to install an application developed by someone else and when running a manage.py command I'm getting this error, which I do not understand.  I wonder if anyone can tell me where to look to investigate first - thank you.

```
POST http://elasticsearch:9200/_bulk?refresh=true [status:N/A request:0.001s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/henry/.virtualenvs/hjsm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 486, in get_or_create
    return self.get(**lookup), False
  File "/home/henry/.virtualenvs/hjsm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/djmoney/models/managers.py", line 209, in wrapper
    queryset = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/henry/.virtualenvs/hjsm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 399, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
providers.models.Organisation.DoesNotExist: Organisation matching query does not exist.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/henry/.virtualenvs/hjsm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 160, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/home/henry/.virtualenvs/hjsm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 57, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 745, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/henry/.virtualenvs/hjsm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 95, in perform_request
    response = self.pool.urlopen(method, url, body, retries=False, headers=self.headers, **kw)
  File "/home/henry/.virtualenvs/hjsm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 641, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/home/henry/.virtualenvs/hjsm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 344, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/home/henry/.virtualenvs/hjsm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 686, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/henry/.virtualenvs/hjsm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 603, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/home/henry/.virtualenvs/hjsm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 355, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1254, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1300, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1249, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1036, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 974, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/home/henry/.virtualenvs/hjsm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 183, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/home/henry/.virtualenvs/hjsm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 169, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f506c988eb8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

**EDIT**

Added `manage.py` as requested

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault('DEPLOY_ENV', 'local')
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'core.settings.%s' % os.environ['DEPLOY_ENV'])

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line  # noqa
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Whether `elastic-search` is running in your local system??

Comment: it is running.  `curl localhost:9200/` give me `{
  "name" : "Stunner",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "8Nj2Cw2mQMOayAxBjxXMWQ",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "2.4.6",
    "build_hash" : "5376dca9f70f3abef96a77f4bb22720ace8240fd",
    "build_timestamp" : "2017-07-18T12:17:44Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "5.5.4"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}`

Comment: Post your `manage.py` code. So that will help to debug

Comment: added `manage.py`

Comment: Look at the first line of your traceback. your script trying to connect to the `http://elasticsearch:9200`

Comment: Arrrrrrggggggggggggggggg!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Goran said, I was trying to connect to elasticsearch:9200 but testing localhost:9200